# Как запустить два процесса python

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота, нужно чтобы был запущен бота, и функция f() срабатывала каждые 30 секунд)

```
import telebot
from settings import bot
import goo
import keyboards
import sched, time
from threading import Thread
print('salam')
from multiprocessing import Process
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def welcome(message):
    print(message.text)
    if message.text[:6] == '/start':
        if message.from_user.username is not None:
            goo.reg(message.from_user.username, message.chat.id, message)
        else:
            if message.from_user.first_name is not None and message.from_user.last_name is not None:
                goo.reg(message.from_user.first_name +' '+ message.from_user.last_name, message.chat.id, message)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У вас недостаточно данных в профиле для регистрации. Пожалуйста заполните профиль и завершите регистрацию.')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def call(call):
    if call.data == 'inf':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=goo.info(call.from_user.id), reply_markup=keyboards.info)
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def f():
    print('proverka')
    s.enter(10, 1, f) 
    goo.bals()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("START")
    proc = Process(target=s.run())
    # Создаём два потока для каждого из методов
    proc1 = Process(target=bot.polling())
    proc.start()
    proc1.start()
    proc.join()
    proc1.join()
     # Запустили один метод на выполнение в потоке
    print('slesh')
```

Comment: Осталось добавить - что вам не нравится в вашем текущем коде. Из вопроса это непонятно.

Comment: Запускается только телеграм бот, а функция f() не запускается

Comment: А я что-то не вижу, где она должна запускаться. Перезапуск - вижу, если я правильно понял. А первоначальный запуск что-то не вижу

Comment: в условии if __main__  s.run()  с помощью Process

Comment: Это я вижу. Но какое отношение имеет `s` к `f`? Внутри `f` я вижу с `s` что-то делается, но для того, чтобы попасть туда, нужно `f` как-то вызвать. Где этот вызов `f`?

Comment: Если я ее вызываю перед main то бот не запускается) программа рекурсивно выполняет f()